# Is running Ubuntu/XP duel boot safe now that XP is being pulled?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm new to askubuntu and I was hoping someone might be able to provide some insight into a question I have. I run a duel-boot PC with Ubuntu/WinXP and, despite XP being pulled this April, I'd like to continue using XP *safely*. The reason for this is that, whilst I have a dual-boot, I use Ubuntu about 95-99% of the time but there is the very rare occasion when I need Windows. What I plan to do is keep Linux as my everyday OS and only use XP without a network connection. What I'd like to know is, would you deem this as safe? With both OS' being on the same drive (albeit on different partitions), is one OS vulnerable to getting a virus from the other i.e Linux to Windows? Can a virus "jump" from one partition to another? I apologise if this sounds trivial but I'm not too clued up on the nature of partitions. I have considered upgrading to Win7/8 but spending £100+ really wouldn't be warranted,

Many thanks,

Rob

Comment: Don't use internet on windows, and you're safe. Also, if you can, try using wine - a linux program that runs windows programs inside linux. If your programs can run on wine, there's no need for Windows. Tell us which programs are you using on windows, and I'll tell you how(and if that's possible) you can run them under wine, and get rid of windows. :D

Comment: Hi Dušan. I forgot to add in my post, I've tried WINE before, apologies for that. I liked how capable it was of running Win programs but what put me off it was the possibility of running malicious executables. As WINE can run  Win programs, surely that includes malware/viruses?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not connect to the internet using XP, it is unlikely that your XP will be infected through Linux. That is, if you do not have a shared FAT or NTFS partition and you do not use the Windows partition to store files on from Linux. By default Windows cannot read ext4 or older.

Another thing is that you are extremely vulnarable if you use other files than the ones you are 100% sure of. Many threats, malware, viruses are "saved" untill the date that support for XP will expire and there will be no fixes developped.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite safe to use XP when disconnected from the internet, however there are three ways I can see that you could have your XP partition infected while doing what you describe (never connecting to the internet when XP is running).

First, if you download an infected file (while on Ubuntu) and then open up or interact with that file in XP, the XP partition could become infected. If you only place files onto your XP partition that are from sources you trust, this is extremely unlikely to happen.

Second, if your Ubuntu install becomes infected, then that infection could infect the XP partition. This is extremely unlikely, and using XP would only cause a minuscule increase to your exposure to the threat of infection.

Third, if you already have an infection on your XP partition (e.g. a virus that waits until XP is unsupported), your XP partition could already be infected. This is unlikely, especially if you have practiced good security habits while using the XP install before the expiration, and if you only interact with files from sources you trust. If you make a clean install of XP and only connect to the internet to download updates, the risk of this happening will be minuscule.

In short, it will be safe to use XP when not connected to the internet if you only interact with files from sources you trust. One way to improve security is to only put files where XP can access it if they are from a source you trust (the Ubuntu partition will likely not be accessible by XP, since it will probably be in the ext3 or ext4 format).